# Is the Bridge of Souls a real location?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the TV show 'The Big Bang Theory' episode 'The Hot Troll Deviation' (season four, episode four), Howard mentions that he got broke up with his ex due to being caught doing certain things under 'The Bridge of Souls' in World of Warcraft.

Is this a real location in World of Warcraft and if so, where is it and how do I get there?

Comment: Theoretically, you can't really get under the Bridge of Souls in Auchenai Crypts, on it yes :)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Bridge of Souls actually exists: you can find it in the [Auchenai Crypts](http://www.wowpedia.org/Auchenai_Crypts), a dungeon in the Outlands zone, Terokkar Forest. Here's its location in the dungeon from the in-game map:

[image: In-game map of the Auchenai Crypts]

And here's an in-game screenshot:

[image: in-game screenshot of the Bridge of Souls]

As you can see, it's a place rife with relationship pitfalls. However, Howard wasn't exactly telling the whole truth: you can't actually go below the Bridge of Souls. You can only cross it to face [Shirrak the Dead Watcher](http://www.wowpedia.org/Shirrak_the_Dead_Watcher) and continue on with the dungeon.

Comment: Ah, yes. Auchenai Crypts. One of the more reviled instances of Burning Crusade. Invulnerable ghosts are never fun.

Comment: @Raven you shut your filthy mouth. Auchenai Crypts was awesome. (Awesome to stealth past the first boss as a rogue and farm a rare enchanting pattern in.)

Comment: This is what you get for not playing during TBC I guess

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I preferred farming the chest in the Mechanar.

Comment: Pffft. Mech chest was for amateurs. Auchenai, Sethekk, Underbog, or go home.

Comment: If you do in fact attempt to go underneath the Bridge of Souls (by getting knocked off of it), you fall into the pit on either side of it and die.